# AB Test Dilemma

Tags: ab-testing

I am running an AB test on a site I launched. If I want to launch a new CTA button on my site and as a result, another section of my site performs worse, how do I account for this or how can I avoid this? The CTA button works great for the siloed effect but the other section does worse.

*This is an interview question*

Comment: I would ask the interviewer how they know that the button caused the poor performance elsewhere... correlation is not causation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: what are the hypotheses behind the new CTA button? Why do you want to introduce this new component? What is the desired outcome?

Second: it is a quite common, but not so mentioned side effect of CTA buttons, as they purpose is to drive the visitor/user/customer to a specific direction instead of visiting other pages on your site. This is why they are called "Call to Action" buttons.

So, what was the plan with the new button? What are the KPI's behind it, and most importantly, why it "hurts" your business if the CTA performs well?

I think, you should prioritize and determine what is the so called red-route on your website. If the CTA button is not part of the red-route but other section what you mention is part of it, then something went wrong during the design process. "Red routes are the critical tasks that deliver the most value to your users". If introducing a new CTA button impacts badly your business, then you should work on this problem first.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the new CTA and the other section are related to each other. Does the new CTA detract from the other section because it adds clarity? Before people where clicking trying to find something and now the new CTA is what they were looking for? Causing less people to click on the other section because what they want to find is easier.